# Раскрытие скобок в PHP

Tags: php

Являюсь студентом и получил практическое задание:

Описание задания
Есть строка:

> {Пожалуйста,|Просто|Если сможете,} сделайте так, чтобы это
>   {удивительное|крутое|простое|важное|бесполезное} тестовое предложение
>   {изменялось {быстро|мгновенно|оперативно|правильно} случайным
>   образом|менялось каждый раз}.

Задача:

1. Строка должна раскрываться согласно следующим правилам:

   - {..|..}  значит, что допустимо одно из указанных значений, то есть {крутое|простое} значит, что выведется ТОЛЬКО крутое или ТОЛЬКО
     простое.
   - Вложенные фигурные скобки так же должны раскрываться, значит: {простое|очень {сложное|удачное}} в итоге получим на выходе один из
     трёх вариантов: "простое", "очень сложное", "очень удачное".
   - Вложенность может быть бесконечной.
2. Необходимо реализовать алгоритм получения всех возможных вариантов раскрытия исходной строки.

Хотел бы попросить помощи направить в верное русло мышления

Comment: Если бы не было вложенности, то ваша задача решалась бы через preg_match_all, rand и str_replace. Вложенность убирается путём многократного повторения вышеописанных действий

Comment: У вас классическая задача по [токенизации](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Токен_(лексический_анализ)), данные которой очень похожи на регулярные выражения. В вашем случае я рекомендую читать строку посимвольно, создавая дерево / список синтаксиса. Смотрите [пример](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtok.php) для этого, но учтите что в PHP нет символа как в других языках, а только строки.

Comment: Если хотите попробовать более современный подход с регулярными выражениями, зайдите на сайт regex101.com или альтернативный, и используйте регулярку \{[а-яА-Я|]*\}Остальное попробуйте додумать сами. (Подсказка: после нахождения всех регулярных выражений в строке вырезайте их оттуда, и снова делайте прогон, но уже без них)

Comment: помню, такая задача была на одном из моих собесов, в нете давно есть решение, ищите))